# Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception

```
    public int getSum(){
        int sum=0;

        for(int i=1; i <= sqlite_master.getRowCount(); i++)
        {
            sum=sum+Integer.parseInt((String) sqlite_master.getValueAt(i, 2));      
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

The code is written in order to get the sum of a particular column in a table of 2 columns with one column strings and other numbers

Error is

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 2
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:474)
```

kindly provide some solution in order to fix the problem

Comment: Indices start at 0 in Java. Not at 1. Why do you store Integers as String, instead of storing them as Integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work better. Indexes start at 0 and go up to row count minus 1.

```
public int getSum(){
        int sum=0;

        for(int i=0; i < sqlite_master.getRowCount(); i++)
        {
            sum=sum+Integer.parseInt((String) sqlite_master.getValueAt(i, 2));      
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: (1+) for posting this as an answer (I was just about to do the same), instead of a comment. Now the OP can "accept" the answer, so people don't need to keep reading a question that already has a solution.

Comment: I updated the code but still the same problem is shown. If possible could you try to give some other method to obtain the same solution.

Comment: @Evan Perhaps you have the same issue with the column index? If you meant to select the second column, you should pass 1 as an index (i.e. `sqlite_master.getValueAt(i, 1)`). Column indexes as any other index also start at 0. Other than that, there is nothing more to see in the small snippet you posted. Consider posting an [MCVE] if this answer and this comment does not solve your problem.

Comment: The problem was the column index and as suggested row index which should have been public int getSum(){
        int sum=0;

        for(int i=0; i < sqlite_master.getRowCount(); i++)
        {
            sum=sum+Integer.parseInt((String) sqlite_master.getValueAt(i, 1));      
        }
        return sum;
    }